# How can I use two if statments and one else statment?

Tags: python

I'm trying to have the code reject someone If they're under 13 and over 20 then, accept when they're over 13. It was working before I added the over 20 part but now I enter a age under 13 it plays both under 13 and else.
Should I have worded it better?

```
if age<13:
  print("sorry young warrior but  you shall not pass.")
if age>20:
  print("Why are you here you old geezer.")
else:
  print("Welcome to the clan!")
```

Comment: The second `if` should be an `elif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interval comparison and have:

```
if 13 < age < 20:
  print("No no no")
else:
  print("Welcome to the clan!")
```

or if you need explicit print statements for these cases, just handle the rest in `elif`:

```
if age<13:
  print("sorry young warrior but  you shall not pass.")
elif age>20:
  print("Why are you here you old geezer.")
else:
  print("Welcome to the clan!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second if should be an elif

Credits to @Nick

Comment: your isn't an answer, should be a comment to the question?